# Pandas merge and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge data that looks something like the following (there are a lot of different files too holding `bar` data). There are a bunch of different data frames, set up like below.

```
id  bar  baz
 1   10   15
 2   12   69

id  bar  baz
 3   96   75

id  bar  baz
 4   45   76
 5   75   23

id  foo  bah
 1  0.1   81
 2  0.2   59
 3  0.1   89
 4  0.1  642
 5  0.2   51
```

I want to merge everything into a single file which has columns `id`, `foo`, `bah`, `bar`, and `baz`. I tried repeated invocations of `df = pd.merge(df, t_df, how='outer', on=key_trans[key])` in a for-loop, but that doesn't work, and instead produces columns `bar_x`, `bar_y`, etc. for each original variable.

Note on above: `key_trans` is a key which gives data that needs to be preserved, like `id` (and other kinds of ids that I've simplified away in asking the question).

Comment: Could you post the format of the other two datarames from which `bar_x` and `bar_y` come from?

Comment: Are they always mutually exclusive?

Comment: You must have used merge instead of concat.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, they are always mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think you've used the wrong function to merge these dataFrames together.

Comment: I've not merged them together.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have multiple `dfs` each with columns like `id` and `foo` and another with `id` and `bar_x` and another with `id` and `bar_y`?

Comment: Also have you created that `df` in your question? If so then you can get to where you want with some stacking.

Comment: I've edited the question, I think that clears up where stuff is located.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below `df`:

```
    bar_x   bar_y   bar_z   foo id
0   10.0    NaN     NaN     0.1 1
1   12.0    NaN     NaN     0.2 2
2   64.0    NaN     NaN     0.1 3
3   NaN     NaN     10.0    0.1 4
4   NaN     12.0    NaN     0.2 5
```

Use:

`df.set_index(['foo', 'id']).sum(axis=1).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'bar'})`

Output:

```
    foo id  bar
0   0.1 1   10.0
1   0.2 2   12.0
2   0.1 3   64.0
3   0.1 4   10.0
4   0.2 5   12.0
```

**With the editing of the question, below solution comes to mind**:

```
df.merge(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True))

   id   foo bar
0   1   0.1 10
1   2   0.2 12
2   3   0.1 96
3   4   0.1 45
4   5   0.2 75
```

Comment: I considered that, but what if I have a list of `bar_x`, `bar_y`, `bar_z`, etc. (running out of letters), then what?

Comment: Edited that in.